# Arithmetic Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-pde

An arithmetic brownian motion $X$ which follows $dX = \mu dt + \sigma dZt$ , where $μ$ and $\sigma$ are constants with an asset price $ S = X^2$.
Use Ito's Lemma, find the DE satisfied by the process S.
What are the  distribution function and the PDF of the process S.

Comment: For the DE it is enough to compute the Ito derivative: $$dS_t = (2\mu \sqrt{S_t} + \sigma^2)dt + 2\sigma \sqrt{S_t}dW_t$$

Comment: For the distribution and the other property take in mind that if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ then $Z/\sigma^2$ is a chi-squared with 1 degree of freedom